# Most Compact File Storage of Time Stamp and String Pairs

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to write a time stamp and string pair to file in the most compact way possible.  I started out writing the string representation of Ticks, then ASCII 31 as a seperator, then the string, then a CR.

Then I realised that as ticks is a long and can be stored as only 8 bytes I should convert ticks to bytes and write those bytes to the file.  That's fine except those timestamp bytes might contain a byte whose value is 31 so my ASCII 31 delimiter is no longer unique.

What is the most compact way to store a timestamp and string pair to file?

Thanks.

Comment: Since Ticks has a fixed maximum length, you could avoid using the separator, reading the first 8 bytes of the _Tick_ and then reading the remaining bytes as the string.

Comment: Of course! Perfect.  Thank you.  Can you convert your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Since *Ticks* has a fixed maximum length, you could avoid using the separator, reading the first 8 bytes of *Ticks* data and then reading the remaining bytes as the string.
:)

Comment: Oh and remember to *pad* the value if necessary!

Comment: Pad the long?  But it will always be 8 bytes won't it?  What should I pad?

Comment: Actually, I don't think this approach is going to work.  I am using a CR to delimit the timestamp/string pair but I can't gaurantee that a CR won't appear in the timestamp.  If I pad the string to be fixed width (which I am guessing is what you are referring to in your comment) I will waste a lot of space as the string length is highly variable.

Comment: No I actually meant to pad the long to 8 bytes, when necessary... About the string, are there some assumptions on the content - is it human readable?

Comment: Kind of.  They are NMEA0183 sentences, an ASCII subset of characters representing 6 bit values, all printable so I know they will not contain CR or other non-printable characters.

Comment: OK, I think I've got it.  I write the eight bytes of the long to file, then a byte that gives the length of the text data (<255), then the text data as byte values.  This way there is only one non-data byte per timestamp-string pair so this seems a very compact.

Comment: If you want to shave a few more bytes at the cost of some time presicion, you could store whole seconds from an origin date intsead of ticks.  An unsigned 4-byte field would store enough whole seconds to be valid for the next 136 years.  Up to you if saving 4 bytes per record is worth it.